# Как вывести различия в двух массивах?

Tags: javascript, массивы, сравнение

Например, есть 2 массива:

```
var days      = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", 
    "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье"];
var work_days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", 
    "Пятница", "Рабочие дни"];
```

Как их сравнить и вывести результат:

```
"Суббота", "Воскресенье", "Рабочие дни"
```

Comment: Пройтись по элементам каждого, отыскивая очередной в соседнем массиве. Если нет – выводить.

Comment: @Sergiks ну можно и не за квадрат решение сделать, хотя бы за n log n. А лучше за n.

Comment: @pavel массивы не отсортированы, как можно сделать за n?  В частном случае, если предположить ограниченный набор возможных значений, задача становится совсем простой. Но этого в вопросе пока нет.

Comment: @Sergiks хеш сет.

Comment: вычисление одного MD5 хэша потребует, вероятно, больше операций, чем O(n^2) по массивам из примера )

Comment: Ну мы же не звери  md5 хеш делать) есть и проще, банальный полиномиальный хеш к примеру.

Comment: линейную асимптотику в общем случае наверное не получить, но например когда элементы массивов не повторяются вполне будет O(n)

Answer (score 5):

Можно примерно так:

```js
var days      = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", 
    "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье"];
var work_days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", 
    "Пятница", "Рабочие дни"];

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify( diff(days, work_days));

function diff( a, b) {
  var diff = a.filter((e)=>!~b.indexOf(e));
  return diff.concat(b.filter((e)=>!~a.indexOf(e)));
}
```

В функцию сравнения `diff()` передаём оба массива. Там с помощью метода `.filter()`, сначала отбираются те элементы `a`, которых нет в `b`. А затем к полученным добавляются наоборот – те из `b`, которых нет в `a`.

Использованы методы: склейка массивов [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), фильтр массива [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: какая сложность этого решения ?

Comment: @ampawd ужасная, O(n^2)

Comment: @ampawd расскажите про решение O(n), считая, что нет повторов (хотя не всё ли равно?)

Comment: заводятся два объекта `Map` ключи которых соотв. это элементы массивов, а значения `true`. далее проходами по исходным массивам идёт проверка на отсутсвие элементов первого во втором, потом ещё одним проходом по второму массиву та же проверка отсутвия второго массива в первом, а элементы прошедшие этот тест и будут разницей двух массивов - тоесть выходит 4 последовательных прохода циклами, что даёт итоговую сложность если быть совсем точным `O(max(n, m))` где n и m размеры, а линейная зависивость обеспечивается за константной работы метода `Map.prototype.has` который будет проверять отсутсвие

Answer (score 2):

Можно подготовить один из массивов и собрать из него объект, с помощью [функции reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), это позволит избавиться от `indexOf`

```js
var days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг",
  "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье"
];
var work_days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг",
  "Пятница", "Рабочие дни"
];

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(diff(days, work_days));

function diff(a, b) {
  var m = days.reduce(function(a, d) {
    a[d] = 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  var r = work_days.reduce(function(acc, el) {
    delete acc.rest[el];
    if (!acc.m[el]) acc.result.push(el);
    return acc;
  }, {
    m: m,
    result: [],
    rest: Object.assign({}, m)
  });
  return r.result.concat(Object.keys(r.rest));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Операция известная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) и реализована в куче библиотек. Один из вариантов — [`lodash.xor`](https://lodash.com/docs#xor):

```js
var days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье"];
var work_days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Рабочие дни"];

var result = _.xor(days, work_days);
alert(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/lodash/lodash/4.13.1/dist/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

решение за O(n) по времени и O(n) по памяти и требующее не повторящихся элементов в массивах.

```js
var days      = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", 
    "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье"];
var workDays = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", 
    "Пятница", "Рабочие дни"];

var diff = [];
var daysAsKeys = new Map();  // need ES6
days.forEach(function(day) {
  daysAsKeys.set(day, true);
});

var workDaysAsKeys = new Map();
workDays.forEach(function(workDay) {
  workDaysAsKeys.set(workDay, true);
});    

days.forEach(function(day) {
  if (!workDaysAsKeys.has(day))
    diff.push(day);
});

workDays.forEach(function(workDay) {
  if (!daysAsKeys.has(workDay))
    diff.push(workDay);
});

alert(diff)
```